# Netgear WiFi Adapter not picking up wifi on channel 12 or 13

Tags: wireless, windows, wine, 14.10, ndiswrapper

I changed OS from Windows 8 to Ubuntu and was using a Netgear WIFI adapter for my windows machine. I is a WNDA3100 v2 adapter supporting 802.11b/g/n and 5GHz.

I used ndiswrapper and Wine to install the driver for the adapter and it picks up wifi from channel 1-11 but my router is on channel 13 and my 5GHz is on channel 48.

Below is "iwconfig"

```
wlan2     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

The IEEE is 802.11g, but the adapter supports b/g/n.

Anyone in similar situation or have managed to solve this?

Comment: What does `iw reg get` reveal?  Some countries cannot use channel 12 or 13

Comment: `country 00: DFS-UNSET
 (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
 (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), NO-IR
 (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
 (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), NO-IR
 (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), NO-IR
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: Hi Mate,

I followed the steps but it is still stuck on 802.11g and cannot pickup any channel 12 or 13

Comment: What do `sudo iw reg get` and `sudo iwkist wlan0 chan` report now?

Comment: sudo iw reg get
`country GB: DFS-UNSET
 (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
 (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
 (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (N/A, 20), DFS
 (5490 - 5710 @ 40), (N/A, 27), DFS
 (57240 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), NO-OUTDOOR
`

Comment: sudo iwlist wlan0 chan
`wlan2     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
`

Comment: It says it's getting 12, 13 and 14. Are you unable to scan and see networks there? Or unable to connect or what?

Comment: I can scan and get networks but it is not picking up anything on channel 12 or 13 or 14. May try a different driver

Comment: I doubt there is more than one driver that works.