# Available networks stopped showing 5GHz networks on Ubuntu 22.10, 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, network-manager, 22.10

I was able to connect my home 5GHz wifi (with _5G suffix on name) on Ubuntu 22.04. After an update via Software Updater, my network list stopped showing 5Ghz networks. I then upgraded Ubuntu to 22.10, but it didn't help. I'm able to connect that network on my phone.

Any help is appreciated!

- `sudo iw reg get` returns

```
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (755 - 928 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

phy#2
country 99: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (5140 - 5360 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (5460 - 5860 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A)
```

- `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` returns

```
[    5.533569] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    5.646689] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie for chip BCM4356/2
[    5.648555] brcmfmac 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.LENOVO-20F6CTO1WW.bin failed with error -2
[    5.652769] brcmfmac 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.LENOVO-20F6CTO1WW.txt failed with error -2
[    5.653284] brcmfmac 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    6.066649] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie for chip BCM4356/2
[    6.072637] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4356/2 wl0: Aug 29 2019 02:05:27 version 7.35.180.197 (r722171 CY) FWID 01-4c8512f9
[    6.441769] brcmfmac 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.443122] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM4356A2-0a5c-640e.hcd'
[    6.443128] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-640e.hcd'
```

- `nmcli device wifi list` returns

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                     MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Flugmodus                Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
 *      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  WLAN13402111             Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  UPC52EFAB5               Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  WLAN14536499             Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  ZTE_D3D0E5               Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  nugget                   Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  UPC45E1A3A               Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Mariahilf                Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  UPCD3AF255               Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  WLAN11763610             Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  bongoverein aegidigasse  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  UPC9426511               Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Doenerbude               Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  --                       Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  37      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Yallah                   Infra  8     130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Innonet-8000             Infra  9     270 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  UPC9369407               Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Drei_H288A_24G_96cF      Infra  9     130 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2
```

- Country code AT is set in `/etc/default/crda`
- `sudo iwlist scan` does not list 5G network.
- `-ThinkPad-X260:~$ sudo lshw -C network` returns

```
 
      *-network                 
           description: Wireless interface
           product: BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           logical name: wlp4s0
           version: 02
           serial: 48:e2:44:93:29:dc
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.180.197 firmware=01-4c8512f9 ip=192.168.0.52 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:130 memory:f1400000-f1407fff memory:f1000000-f13fffff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 1f.6
           bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
           logical name: enp0s31f6
           version: 21
           serial: 50:7b:9d:eb:64:91
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:126 memory:f1600000-f161ffff
```

- `iw list` result

```
Wiphy phy0
   wiphy index: 0
   max # scan SSIDs: 10
   max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
   max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
   max # match sets: 16
   Retry short limit: 7
   Retry long limit: 4
   Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
   Device supports roaming.
   Supported Ciphers:
       * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
       * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
       * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
       * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
       * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
   Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
   Supported interface modes:
        * IBSS
        * managed
        * AP
        * P2P-client
        * P2P-GO
        * P2P-device
   Band 1:
       Capabilities: 0x1022
           HT20/HT40
           Static SM Power Save
           RX HT20 SGI
           No RX STBC
           Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
           DSSS/CCK HT40
       Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
       Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
       HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
       Bitrates (non-HT):
           * 1.0 Mbps
           * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
           * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
           * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
           * 6.0 Mbps
           * 9.0 Mbps
           * 12.0 Mbps
           * 18.0 Mbps
           * 24.0 Mbps
           * 36.0 Mbps
           * 48.0 Mbps
           * 54.0 Mbps
       Frequencies:
           * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
           * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm)
   Band 2:
       Capabilities: 0x1062
           HT20/HT40
           Static SM Power Save
           RX HT20 SGI
           RX HT40 SGI
           No RX STBC
           Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
           DSSS/CCK HT40
       Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
       Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
       HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
       VHT Capabilities (0x0c015820):
           Max MPDU length: 3895
           Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
           short GI (80 MHz)
           SU Beamformer
           SU Beamformee
       VHT RX MCS set:
           1 streams: MCS 0-9
           2 streams: MCS 0-9
           3 streams: not supported
           4 streams: not supported
           5 streams: not supported
           6 streams: not supported
           7 streams: not supported
           8 streams: not supported
       VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
       VHT TX MCS set:
           1 streams: MCS 0-9
           2 streams: MCS 0-9
           3 streams: not supported
           4 streams: not supported
           5 streams: not supported
           6 streams: not supported
           7 streams: not supported
           8 streams: not supported
       VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
       VHT extended NSS: not supported
       Bitrates (non-HT):
           * 6.0 Mbps
           * 9.0 Mbps
           * 12.0 Mbps
           * 18.0 Mbps
           * 24.0 Mbps
           * 36.0 Mbps
           * 48.0 Mbps
           * 54.0 Mbps
       Frequencies:
           * 5170 MHz [34] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5720 MHz [144] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm)
           * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm)
   Supported commands:
        * new_interface
        * set_interface
        * new_key
        * start_ap
        * join_ibss
        * set_pmksa
        * del_pmksa
        * flush_pmksa
        * remain_on_channel
        * frame
        * set_wiphy_netns
        * set_channel
        * start_sched_scan
        * start_p2p_device
        * connect
        * disconnect
        * crit_protocol_start
        * crit_protocol_stop
        * update_connect_params
   WoWLAN support:
        * wake up on disconnect
        * wake up on magic packet
        * wake up on pattern match, up to 8 patterns of 1-128 bytes,
          maximum packet offset 1500 bytes
        * can do GTK rekeying
        * wake up on GTK rekey failure
        * wake up on network detection, up to 16 match sets
   software interface modes (can always be added):
   valid interface combinations:
        * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
          total <= 3, #channels <= 2
        * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
          total <= 4, #channels <= 1
   Device supports scan flush.
   max # scan plans: 1
   max scan plan interval: 508
   max scan plan iterations: 0
   Supported TX frame types:
        * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
   Supported RX frame types:
        * managed: 0x40 0xd0
        * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
        * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
        * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
        * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
   Supported extended features:
       * [ CQM_RSSI_LIST ]: multiple CQM_RSSI_THOLD records
       * [ DFS_OFFLOAD ]: DFS offload
```

Comment: What is the hardware in your system?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1456839/edit) your question and add more details about your hardware, i.e. `sudo lshw -C network`.  Also, please don't use screenshots, but use copy and paste instead.  You can use the { } button for code formatting when pasting.

Comment: @Terrance done, thanks!

Comment: What is the result of: `nmcli device wifi rescan` and: `nmcli device wifi list` Please redact any MAC addresses with XXXX. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555, `nmcli device wifi rescan` returns no result. `nmcli device wifi list` result is added in the question. Thanks! Note that `WLAN13402111_5G` is not shown in the results and that's what I'm looking for and am able to connect via my phone

Comment: Let's have a look at: `sudo dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: Please confirm that your router, WLAN13402111_5G, is set to a *fixed* channel, one of those listed above, 149 for example, and certainly not auto channel select.

Comment: @chili555, `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` returned some errors, I added the output in the question. Regarding router channel setting, the channel config has been set to auto, I haven't touched it before. Since you mentioned it, I tried `48`, `44` it didn't help. I also tried to set it to `128` ,  `124`, but setting page warns like "Channel 128 is a DFS channel. Are you sure?" then I confirm but I still see the previous channel is set (e.g. `44`). Somehow, I can't set channel to one of DFS channels.

Comment: Additionally such settings are selected: 
`Wireless mode` : `802.11a/n/ac mixed`
`Channel width` : `20/40/80 MHz`

Comment: @chili555, shall I use a similar approach like here https://askubuntu.com/a/1260886/1676104, wdyt?

Comment: I am finally able to set channel to `128`. I set `Channel width` : `20 MHz` first, then set the channel. _5G still didn't appear, also stopped appearing on my phone. I tried `20/40` and finally `20/40/80 MHz` options sequentially but it doesn't appear both on my pc and phone.

Comment: Update: Config somehow is back to channel 36 after the steps above. It doesn't let me to set channel 128 (or 124)

Comment: "shall I use a similar approach like here" I doubt it will make a difference because a suitable firmware is found; i.e.  brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin. There are many copies on the net of the txt file, unfortunately this file is board-specific so it is probably not useful to use a txt file for a different board. Does using a fixed channel 36 help?

Comment: @chili555, unfortunately channel 36 didn't work either (as well as 48, 44). What could I do/try next, may I ask if you have any ideas?

Comment: Let's see: `sudo iw reg get`

Comment: @chili555, question is updated

Comment: Please try setting your regulatory domain like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/608568/netgear-wifi-adapter-not-picking-up-wifi-on-channel-12-or-13/608740#608740 Then rescan: `nmcli device wifi rescan` and list: `nmcli device wifi list` Any change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143284/discussion-between-jemo-and-chili555).

Comment: @chili555, sorry to bother you again. Since you are experienced about this topic, I wanted to ask you what I can do next to get a solution for the issue. I see many questions around this topic, some people having same/similar issues. Can I place a bug ticket on ubuntu maybe? Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't any other useful suggestions. I would certainly file a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I went back to `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`  with a clean install. Now, I'm able to see and connect my 5G wifi network.